# scipy minimization/optimization of simple function

Tags: python, optimization

I'm having trouble optimizing a very simple function I'm using as a test case before moving on to something more complex. I've tried different optimization methods, giving the method a bound and even giving the exact solution as the initial guess.

Function I'm trying to optimize: `f(x) = 1 / x - x`

Here is my code:

```
import scipy
def testfun(x): return (1 / x - x) 

sol = scipy.optimize.minimize(testfun, 1).x
```

it returns large numbers (3.2 e+08) as the solution

Am I using the optimization function incorrectly?

Comment: What do you think the answer should be? It looks to me like this function is miminzed at x=infinity

Comment: @VictorChubukov my bad I am looking for root finding methods so that f(x) = 0. I think scipy.optimize.newton will do what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Ok (comment removed as original comment was edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Victor mentioned, the optimization function is working correctly,

I was looking to solve `f(x) --> 0` which requires a root finding method rather than an optimization routine.

for example:

`scipy.optimize.root(testfun, 1)` or `scipy.optimize.Newton(testfun, 1)`